# How to create a second featured image box for posts in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have template and in posts, I need to upload a thumbnail and banner which are separate image
I mean banner it does not look like the thumbnail. I can't use plugin and I don't want to do

```
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
add_theme_support('post-banner');
```

I knew the code I entered is wrong, the point is I don't know how I start this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Step 1**: Add the below code in your theme's functions.php

```
// Add second featured image
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'listing_image_add_metabox' );
function listing_image_add_metabox () {
    add_meta_box( 'listingimagediv', __( 'Listing Image', 'text-domain' ), 'listing_image_metabox', 'post', 'side', 'low');
}

function listing_image_metabox ( $post ) {
    global $content_width, $_wp_additional_image_sizes;

    $image_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_listing_image_id', true );

    $old_content_width = $content_width;
    $content_width = 254;

    if ( $image_id && get_post( $image_id ) ) {

        if ( ! isset( $_wp_additional_image_sizes['post-thumbnail'] ) ) {
            $thumbnail_html = wp_get_attachment_image( $image_id, array( $content_width, $content_width ) );
        } else {
            $thumbnail_html = wp_get_attachment_image( $image_id, 'post-thumbnail' );
        }

        if ( ! empty( $thumbnail_html ) ) {
            $content = $thumbnail_html;
            $content .= '<p class="hide-if-no-js"><a href="javascript:;" id="remove_listing_image_button" >' . esc_html__( 'Remove listing image', 'text-domain' ) . '</a></p>';
            $content .= '<input type="hidden" id="upload_listing_image" name="_listing_cover_image" value="' . esc_attr( $image_id ) . '" />';
        }

        $content_width = $old_content_width;
    } else {

        $content = '<img src="" style="width:' . esc_attr( $content_width ) . 'px;height:auto;border:0;display:none;" />';
        $content .= '<p class="hide-if-no-js"><a title="' . esc_attr__( 'Set listing image', 'text-domain' ) . '" href="javascript:;" id="upload_listing_image_button" id="set-listing-image" data-uploader_title="' . esc_attr__( 'Choose an image', 'text-domain' ) . '" data-uploader_button_text="' . esc_attr__( 'Set listing image', 'text-domain' ) . '">' . esc_html__( 'Set listing image', 'text-domain' ) . '</a></p>';
        $content .= '<input type="hidden" id="upload_listing_image" name="_listing_cover_image" value="" />';

    }

    echo $content;
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'listing_image_save', 10, 1 );
function listing_image_save ( $post_id ) {
    if( isset( $_POST['_listing_cover_image'] ) ) {
        $image_id = (int) $_POST['_listing_cover_image'];
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_listing_image_id', $image_id );
    }
}


function wpdocs_selectively_enqueue_admin_script( $hook ) {
    if ( 'post.php' != $hook ) {
        return;
    }
    wp_enqueue_script( 'secondimage', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/secondimage.js', array(), '1.0' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_selectively_enqueue_admin_script' );
```

**Step 2**: Create a second-image.js any inside your theme folder and paste the below code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    // Uploading files
    var file_frame;

    jQuery.fn.upload_listing_image = function (button) {
        var button_id = button.attr('id');
        var field_id = button_id.replace('_button', '');

        // If the media frame already exists, reopen it.
        if (file_frame) {
            file_frame.open();
            return;
        }

        // Create the media frame.
        file_frame = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
            title: jQuery(this).data('uploader_title'),
            button: {
                text: jQuery(this).data('uploader_button_text'),
            },
            multiple: false
        });

        // When an image is selected, run a callback.
        file_frame.on('select', function () {
            var attachment = file_frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
            jQuery("#" + field_id).val(attachment.id);
            jQuery("#listingimagediv img").attr('src', attachment.url);
            jQuery('#listingimagediv img').show();
            jQuery('#' + button_id).attr('id', 'remove_listing_image_button');
            jQuery('#remove_listing_image_button').text('Remove listing image');
        });

        // Finally, open the modal
        file_frame.open();
    };

    jQuery('#listingimagediv').on('click', '#upload_listing_image_button', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        jQuery.fn.upload_listing_image(jQuery(this));
    });

    jQuery('#listingimagediv').on('click', '#remove_listing_image_button', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        jQuery('#upload_listing_image').val('');
        jQuery('#listingimagediv img').attr('src', '');
        jQuery('#listingimagediv img').hide();
        jQuery(this).attr('id', 'upload_listing_image_button');
        jQuery('#upload_listing_image_button').text('Set listing image');
    });

});
```

Replace the above js path with your path. And to use other than post edit page, just replace the post.php in the 'wpdocs_selectively_enqueue_admin_script' function with custom post type you wish to use.

Comment: And then how can I call the image in front-end?

Comment: <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_listing_image_id')[0], 'post-thumbnail'); ?>