# How can I display the featured icon on frontend?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields, meta-boxes

Hello I applied the code I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62860289/how-to-create-a-second-featured-image-box-for-posts-in-wordpress).

But I can't figure out how can I call this image on frontend.

I tried this so far:

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'katastima');
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->next_post();
$id= $the_query->post->ID;
$location = get_post_meta($id, 'listingimagediv', true);
echo $location;
endwhile;
```

but I guess this is not the correct way to get the image link from the custom metabox.
Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the photo ID from get_post_meta
So the next step is to get the url of the image, [see here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/)

```
$size = 'full';
$icon = null;
$attr = array( "class" => "img-responsive" );
echo wp_get_attachment_image( $location, $size, $icon, $attr );
```